# i have this error in my laravel.log file. I don't know what is happening

Tags: php, laravel

SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction in /var/$
Stack trace:

Comment: Welcome to SO ... will definitely need more information and context than that

Comment: It happen when we run the queue.this is not my code. this is code of Queue Job engine.

Comment: Google for "SQL deadlock" and you will find hundreds of pages telling you what a _deadlock_ is. As for a real answer, you haven't provided any code, so there's nothing to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you clear caches in your system , Check with below commands in your CMD or terminal,

```
php artisan route:list
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```